# MS Access on window parallels VM connect to MySQL server on Linux parallels VM

Tags: mysql, ms-access, networking, connection, virtual-machine

my computer OS system is OS X , and I have two parallels desktop VM ( window and linux ) , I have installed MySQL server on Linux VM and MS Access on Window VM ,
I have some data in the MySQL server.

The question is how can I connect the MS Access to the MySQL server ???
( I have searched a lot , but still can't succeed in doing that.)

I have installed the mySQL ODBC driver on Window, but when I use Access, trying to link to the MySQL server ,  it shows "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'(10061)"
( I type  127.0.0.1 in "TCP/IP Server:"  , 3306 in "Port:")

Anyone can provide a specific solution??? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is *localhost*, your current machine.

To access any other machine, use the IP address of that. For your Linux VM, it can be found in the settings of Parallels for the NIC (virtual network card) of the machine.